# Refresh 2 divs with 1 ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, intervals

Say I have 2 divs, how I can I refresh them both every 5 seconds with 1 ajax request?

```
<div id='1'></div>

<div id='2'></div>
```

I can refresh 1 like this:

```
  interval = setTimeout(refreshpage, 5000);
  function refreshpage() {
     $('#1').load('page.php?&timer='+new Date().getTime()+' #1');
     interval = setTimeout(refreshpage, 5000);
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean, with 1 ajax request? you can't get 2 pages at the same time. You can create 2 ajax reqeuests that resolve promises, defer them, and call `$.when()` for when they both complete, but other than that, no.

Comment: Don't use `.load()` as that displays the results in the jQuery object you chain it to. Instead use `$.get()` or `$.ajax()`, return json and process the different parts in the ajax success function.

Comment: @ohgodwhy the divs are are the same page.

Comment: @jeroen example please?

Comment: You should check the jQuery manual and there are lots of examples here on SO.

Comment: You should never assume that the call is completed at a certain point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, assuming you want the same ajax call to populate the 2 different div's you would do something like this:

Here's your HTML:

```
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
```

So, you can just do the ajax request individually and then load that same request into the 2 divs:

```
interval = setTimeout(refreshpage, 5000);

function refreshpage() {
    var data = $.get('page.php?&timer='+new Date().getTime()+' #1').done(function (response) {
        ('#1').html(response);
        ('#2').html(response);
    });

    interval = setTimeout(refreshpage, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Also, ID's should never start with an integer.

Comment: @ohgodwhy i know, just an example man..

Comment: @DobotJr Might help googler's in the future. you never know. :)

Comment: @ohgodwhy you're right

Answer (score 0):

What you actually can do is set a timer with setTimeOut function a

```
 setTimeout(function(){ . . Your ajax Request goes here

 var datos = $.get('page.php?&timer='+new Date().getTime()+'
 #1').done(function (res) {
         $('#1').html(res);
         $('#2').html(res); . . }, 3000);
```